What happened to the off-topic because this is a basic programming question flag?
What happened to the off-topic because this is a basic programming question flag? What are we supposed to flag / vote to close programming questions where the answer is writing or explaining code?

You can use a custom closing reason

Please flag as off-topic. If it's a good question but off-topic, you can flag it as "belongs to other stackexchange site".
